# How do I stop a thread?

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I am starting a new thread in my app's `onCreate()` method like so:

```
stepsLogger = new Runnable() { 

while(!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()){

    //my code

    try {
        Thread.currentThread().sleep(10000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
};

loggerThread = new Thread(stepsLogger);
loggerThread.start();
```

While it is not `interrupted`, it is supposed to do its thing every 10 seconds.

I am logging some text at the start of the `Runnable` to see how often the code gets run. The first time I run the app it's fine, but every time i restart, the text gets logged more frequently which means that more threads are running.

I have tried to stop them in the onDestroy() method:

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    loggerThread.interrupt();
    loggerThread = null;
}
```

How do I make sure that the old thread gets stopped whenever the app is restarted?

Comment: loggerThread.stop();

Comment: Interrupting is the right idea, but from the looks of it, the interrupt is never called.

Comment: @bowmore I think you're right. I added a Log.i() to the onDestroy. When I click on debug app, it just prints "Launching app" and nothing else.

Comment: I'm not an Android specialist, but I would think you need to do the interrupt elsewhere.

Comment: There's no guarantee that `onDestroy()` will be called in an Activity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Thread.interrupt()` will wake up a sleeping thread with an `InterruptedException`, so you're most of the way there already.  I'd change your loop in the following way:

```
while (true) {
  // some code
  try {
    Thread.currentThread().sleep(10000);
  } catch (InterruptedException e) {
    Thread.currentThread().interrupt(); // restore the thread's interrupted flag
    break;
  }
}
```

The bit about re-interrupting the thread is subtle.  You can read more about it in this post from one of the primary JVM architects: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-jtp05236/

In case this link ever dies, the gist of it is that there can be multiple "recipients" of thread interruption.  Catching the exception implicitly clears the thread's interrupted flag, so it's useful to set it again.

Comment: The loop int the OP is fine, and as the Runnable is at the root of the stack, re-interrupting is actually not needed in this case.

Comment: Thanks, that worked! It is still needed to interrupt it in the `onDestroy()`, though. It seems that when one of the interrupts doesn't get called, the other one will. Also, setting loggerThread to null seems to have been unnecessary as it works without it.

Comment: @bowmore you're right, of course - it's not necessary; just good thread hygiene.  When this loop gets copied over to an executor service task, it will be quite helpful :)

Comment: You're absolutely right, it was refreshing to see someone actually handling an InterruptedException properly.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a volatile boolean variable to determine when to stop. Something like this:

```
class WorkerRunnable implements Runnable {

    private volatile boolean shouldKeepRunning = true;
    public void terminate() {
        shouldKeepRunning = false;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (shouldKeepRunning) {
            // Do your stuff
        }
    }
}
```

To start it:

```
WorkerRunnable runnable = new WorkerRunnable();
new Thread(runnable).start();
```

To stop it:

```
runnable.terminate();
```